# Two geometric/arithmetic math tasks

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to apolagize in advance if the questions are too easy but I tried on my own and apparently I didn't make it, so please help.Also write down every single step in the solutions without omitting anything that you may consider as obvious.

First task:

Comment: what equations do you get?

Answer (score 0):

after the conditions of the problem we get the following equations
$$a_1q+1=a_1+d$$
$$a_1q^2-2=a_1+2d$$
$$a_1q^3-13=a_1+3d$$
solving this we get $$a_1=4,d=5,q=2$$

Answer (score 0):

Task $1$:

we know that that followig is an arithmetic sequence:
 $$a, aq + 1, aq^2 - 2, aq^3-13$$

Hence $$aq+1-a=aq^2-2-(aq+1)=aq^3-13-(aq^2-2)$$

$$aq+1-a=aq^2-aq-3=aq^3-aq^2-11$$

From $aq+1-a=aq^2-aq-3$, we have $aq^2-2aq+a-4=0$, that is $$a=\frac{4}{q^2-2q+1}=\left(\frac{2}{q-1}\right)^2$$

From $aq^2-aq-3=aq^3-aq^2-11$, we have $aq^3-2aq^2+aq-8=0$

$$a=\frac{8}{q^3-2q^2+q}=\frac{8}{q(q-1)^2}$$

Hence $$\frac{4}{(q-1)^2}=\frac{8}{q(q-1)^2}$$

Hence $q=2$ and $a=4$.

Task $2$:

$$\frac{X(X+1)}{2}=X^2-55$$

$$X^2+X=2X^2-110$$

$$X^2-X-110=0$$
$$(X+10)(X-11)=0$$

since $X>0$, $X=11$.